# If it's possible to detect if the v-on:change event has been called by specific method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a timepicker that accepts the time chosen manually by the end-user and by setting a current time by clicking on the "Current time" button.

In case and the time set by the user(manually) I have to display the pending icon. In case and I click on the "Current time" button, this icon should be ignored.

I have v-on:change event that calls the "changeTime()" method for setting manually the needed time. In this case, the pending icon should be displayed.

But in case and I click on the "Current time" button , the time is changed to the current one ,the v-on:change event works, and as in result the "changeTime()" method calls .

How can I avoid call the v-on:change event if I use setTime() method?

all code in
time.vue

```
        <vue-timepicker
         manual-input
         format="HH:mm:ss"
         ref="time"
         id="time"
         :value="timeValue"
         v-on:change="changeTime($event, 'time')"
         ></vue-timepicker>
```

And I have a button with onclick event that calls the setTime() method.

```
        <button
        id="currentTimeId"
        v-on:click="setTime"
         >Current Time
         </button>
```

The setTime() method sets the current time to the timepicker:

```
 setTime() {
  let h;
  let m;
  let s;
  h = this.$store.getters.rtcDate["hour"];
  m = this.$store.getters.rtcDate["minute"];
  s = this.$store.getters.rtcDate["second"];
  this.time = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
},
```

Sorry for the complexity.
Thanks.

Comment: Could you post more of your code here, including where you're calling `setTime()` from, and the contents of the `changeTime` and `setTime` functions

Comment: Why not call `changeTime` from `setTime`?

Comment: Thats the point, I don't want to call changeTime()  from the setTime(). I would like to avoid it or at least to know that the time has been changed by setTime() and set some condition.

Comment: That's the first time you said that.  What you said previously was how can I avoid calling it AFTER `setTime`.  And you haven't made it clear why you don't want.  Sounds like an XY problem so far.

Comment: It's hard to understand your question fully without seeing all of your code and knowing how it fits together. What's in `changeTime()`? And how does your `button` element relate to the `vue-timepicker` component?

Comment: I added more description. Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to use the `lazy` prop on the `vue-timepicker` ([more on that here](https://phoenixwong.github.io/vue2-timepicker/#lazyEvents))
2. Create a separate function for updating the data attribute where you store the actual time value
3. Add two different methods for the two different sources of change (`setTime` & `manualSetTime` in the snippet)
4. Add the events to `manualSetTime` that you want to be executed on user click changing the `vue-timepicker` value
5. Add the events to `setTime` that you want to be executed on the button click

(If you cannot use the snippet because of the **console.log**, just click on `Full page` above it)

```js
// "importing" VueTimepicker from the CDN
const VueTimepickerCdn = VueTimepicker.default

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
    VueTimepickerCdn
  },
  data() {
    return {
      stringTimeValueWithSec: null,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    // setting the time for both user & admin
    changeTime($event, msg) {
      this.stringTimeValueWithSec = $event.data
    },
    // user action results
    manualSetTime($event, msg) {
      this.changeTime($event, msg)
      console.log("user click: all events that should be executed on manually changing the vue-timepicker value")
    },
    // admin action result
    setTime() {
      const $event = {
        data: {
          "HH": "00",
          "H": "0",
          "hh": "12",
          "a": "am",
          "A": "AM",
          "h": "12",
          "kk": "24",
          "k": "24",
          "m": "0",
          "mm": "00",
          "s": "0",
          "ss": "00"
        }
      }
      this.changeTime($event, 'admin')
      console.log('non-user click: all events that should be executed on button-click')
    },
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      {{ stringTimeValueWithSec }}<br />
      <vue-timepicker-cdn
        lazy
        format="h:mm:ss A"
        :value="stringTimeValueWithSec"
        @change="manualSetTime($event, 'time')"
      ></vue-timepicker-cdn><br />
    <button
      @click="setTime"
    >
      CURRENT TIME
    </button>
    </div>
  `
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue2-timepicker@1.1.6/dist/VueTimepicker.umd.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue2-timepicker@1.1.6/dist/VueTimepicker.min.css">

<div id="app"></div>
```